# Comments can't contain this content?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, hyperlinks, blocklist

Okay, I've seen the "posts can't contain that content" messages; now I got one popping up when I try to post this comment in response to a comment to me:

> @Ole: thanks for the [URL](http: // efreedom .com /Question/2-96245/Linux-Debian-Pee-Moreutils) (though I had to fix it with the correct scheme and no embedded spaces). I note that `pee` has different semantics from `tpipe` on several counts: most notably, `tpipe` keeps writing to available pipes until they are all closed, rather than stopping on the first error as `pee` does. The `bash` facilities are good if `bash` is reliably available on all platforms of interest, saving me the job. (The URL in the tail of my answer points to the same notation, but not the same article) as yours.

---

Is EFreedom on the banned URL list too?  Or is there a bug in the comments on SO?  Well, since the "Sorry, posts can't contain that content" message pops up, I guess the answer is "Yes, EFreedom is a banned URL".

1. How can we tell which URLs are banned and where is the explanation of why they are banned?
2. Is it really necessary to ban them?
3. The error message needs to explain what is wrong - or provide a link to the explanation of what is wrong.

---

I ended up getting this comment posted:

> @Ole: thanks for the URL (I had to fix it with the correct scheme and no embedded spaces, but [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75165) is being nasty about EFreedom). I note that pee has different semantics from tpipe on several counts: most notably, tpipe keeps writing to available pipes until they are all closed, rather than stopping on the first error as pee does. The bash facilities are good if bash is reliably available on all platforms of interest, saving me the job. (The URL in the tail of my answer points to the same notation, but not the same article) as yours.

But it shouldn't be that difficult!

Comment: I've been seeing this a lot recently when trying to comment on questions I'm reviewing. Most recently, I tried to ask: `What have you tried so far?` only to be told `Comments can't contain this content`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can we tell which URLs are banned and where is the explanation of why they are banned?

Well, since the reason URLs are banned is because the Team thinks they're bad links and are trying to hide them from the internet, so it sort of defeats the purpose for them to publish a full list. There might be a list here on Meta, but I don't remember one.

> Is it really necessary to ban them?

In this particular case, eFreedom copies their content from other sites—specifically, Stack Exchange. Since they just have copies of our questions, the Team prefers you link to the original for SEO purposes.

> The error message needs to explain what is wrong - or provide a link to the explanation of what is wrong.

I agree.

Comment: I'm all in favour of linking back directly to 'The Trilogy' sites - I hadn't scrutinized the eFreedom page so I hadn't noticed the URL linking back to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/96245/linux-debian-what-does-pee-in-moreutils-do) (it was there - so some credit was given where due).  But since I had no clue why my content was objectionable, it spawned this question - which is far more irritating than a popup box that says "URLS containing eFreedom are banned because they copy StackExchange questions".

Comment: @jonathan you can read here for more detail. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/trouble-in-the-house-of-google.html That article has been linked on CNN, The Atlantic, etc..