# Cannot update my existing older answer (S,PCCTC error)

Tags: discussion, lmgtfy

I am trying to be a good community member and update my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055838/best-commercial-html-to-pdf-c-sharp-component on SO with the latest information from my current research.  However, the blacklist rules have changed since my last update and now I can't update my answer with the latest Q1 2012 information.

An experiment to remove all of the content and slowly add it back in section by section (to determine the offending nuggets) carries the risk that the existing answer would not be allowed back in, so I am cautious to undertake that bit of science.

**My question is**, do I have too many links (21)?  Are there blacklisted sites among the links?  Should I remove the links and let users find the companies on their own in the hopes that the content will pass muster?  I figured it would be a timesaver and I have already done the research.

I totally understand the rationale behind the design choice behind restricting content, blacklisting sites and NOT telling the user why their content is offending SO.  I've also read the following:

[I am trying to fix up an answer, but I am told that "posts can't contain that content."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106891/i-am-trying-to-fix-up-an-answer-but-i-am-told-that-posts-cant-contain-that-co)

[Why do I get: Sorry, posts can't contain that content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92929/why-do-i-get-sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content)

["Posts can't contain that content" messages fail to point out the offending part of the content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45895/posts-cant-contain-that-content-messages-fail-to-point-out-the-offending-part)

["Sorry, posts can't contain that content" message is a guessing game with no shells](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content-message-is-a-guessing-game-with-no-she)

["Sorry, posts can't contain that content." what content exactly (besides lmgtfy)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content-what-content-exactly-besides-lmgtfy)

[Comments can't contain this content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75165/comments-cant-contain-this-content)

Comment: That's quite the comprehensive answer to an incredibly not constructive question.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're SOL.  Not even I have enough mojo to change your answer.  The question is borderline "Not Constructive" anyway.

Comment: I have a suspicion I've seen spam relating to one of those links, but since I can't [search my flag history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120283/searching-posts-ive-flagged) I can't easily confirm that.